# Hide the icon in the ActionBar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am trying to hide the application logo from the ActionBar. In order to do that I am using the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)` method:

```
this.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This works almost as intented, except for two things:

- The icon is still visible when the application starts (and then disappear)
- The navigation drawer icon is not visible on some devices (for example on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3)

How can I fix this?

Comment: try this may be help getActionBar().setIcon(
    new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
      android.R.color.transparent)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The icon is still visible when the application starts (and then disappear)

To avoid this you need to undisplay your logo from your `style.xml` as follows:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/mActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="mActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Because your app starts with loading your `Theme` and then after displays your UI by your `Activity`. Also, this will be a resource way, because your activities will not reload the UI like the home icon, etc. since they are first initialized thanks to the theme.

> The navigation drawer icon is not visible on some devices

Make sure you have this following snippnet code:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this,                  /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
    R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
) {

    /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    }
}; 

//...

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And check your icon, or [(re)download it](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html#theme=light&color=33b5e5,40).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works great. I only had to use `android:logo` in my theme instead of `android:icon`.

Comment: Very glad to help. Apparently, `android:logo` is available in API Level 10, but not API Level 8. It can't find a confirmation. However, I always used icon, so I wrote it instead of `logo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);`